# I set 'truncation=True' when using Tapas Tokenizer in transformers, but still get a warning of not setting truncation explicitly

Tags: nlp, pytorch, tokenize, huggingface-transformers

The warning is:

> Truncation was not explicitly activated but `max_length` is provided
> a specific value, please use `truncation=True` to explicitly truncate
> examples to max length. Defaulting to 'longest_first' truncation
> strategy. If you encode pairs of sequences (GLUE-style) with the
> tokenizer you can select this strategy more precisely by providing a specific strategy to `truncation`.

and my code is

```
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("google/tapas-base")
item = tokenizer(table = table, queries = queries, max_length = 256, truncation=True)
```

The version of my transformers 4.15.0. I really wonder what the problem is.

Comment: I can not reproduce this with `4.21.1`. Can you please check if an upgrade of your package helps?